# Direct to S3 Image Uploads in Rails and React

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, amazon-s3, axios

I want to upload image directly from the client side, but I cannot do it well. Can anybody help me?

**version**:

1. Rails 5.1.1
2. ruby 2.4.1
3. aws-sdk 2.10.3

**my logic**

1. drug and drop the image to the Dropzone field
2. make ajax call by axios, then get the signedUrl
3. upload the image file by making the put request with the signedUrl

**Client Side (react)**: I'm using react-dropzone

```
handleOnDrop = (files) => {
    files.map(file => this.uploadImage(file))
}

uploadImage = (file) =>{
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/upload/',
    {
      params: {
        filename: file.name
      }
    })
      .then(res => { 
        const signedUrl = res.data.url;
        return axios.put(signedUrl, file) 
      })
      .then((result) => console.log(result))
      .catch(e => console.log(e));
}

...
<Dropzone onDrop={this.handleOnDrop} >
```

**Server Side(Rails)**

*config*

```
Aws.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-2',
  credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'], ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']),
})

S3_BUCKET = Aws::S3::Resource.new.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET'])
controller
class S3Controller < ApplicationController
  def upload
     render json: S3_BUCKET.object("uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/#{params[:filename]}").presigned_url(:get)
  end
end
```

*routes.rb*

```
...
get 'upload', to: 's3#upload'
...
```

*controller*

```
class S3Controller < ApplicationController
  def upload
     render json: S3_BUCKET.object("uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/#{params[:filename]}").presigned_url(:get)
  end
end
```

**Error Log**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined
    at isURLSameOrigin (eval at <anonymous> (webpack-bundle.self-2cf7062….js?body=1:3328), <anonymous>:57:21)
    at dispatchXhrRequest (eval at <anonymous> (webpack-bundle.self-2cf7062….js?body=1:2070), <anonymous>:109:50)
    at Promise (<anonymous>)
    at xhrAdapter (eval at <anonymous> (webpack-bundle.self-2cf7062….js?body=1:2070), <anonymous>:12:10)
    at dispatchRequest (eval at <anonymous> (webpack-bundle.self-2cf7062….js?body=1:3265), <anonymous>:52:10)
    at <anonymous>
```